# Inicio de escritura de input

Tags: html

El input normal comienza desde la izquierda, como se puede iniciar a escribir desde el medio?

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Sería ideal que añadieras información sobre lo que hayas intentado y los problemas o dificultades que te encontraste. Tal y como está redactada la pregunta es algo pobre y ha sido reportada como de baja calidad. Por favor, completa el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento básico del sitio y lee [ask] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para mejorar tus preguntas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr ese cometido, debemos aplicar con CSS la propiedad **text-align: center;** del modo siguiente

> Como notas accedo al input desde su id por medio de la regla css y le
>   aplico la propiedad antes mencionada

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    #saludo{
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="saludo">
</body>
</html>
```